# Sqoop fails to import data from Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, hadoop, import, sqoop

`sqoop import --driver="com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver" --connect="jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://**.**.**.** :1433/DB_Schema;Integrated Security=TRUE"  --table dbo.TABLE_NAME`

Error 1:

> --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager).Sqoop is going to
>   fall back to `org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager`. Please
>   specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.

Error 2 :

> Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException:Could not load
>   db driver class: `com.microsoft.jdbc.sqlserver.SQLServerDriver`

- Sqoop version : Sqoop 1.4.6
- Hadoop version : Hadoop 2.6.0
- Java version : 1.7.0_51
- SQL jar : sqljdbc4.jar

What could be the reason.

Comment: The sqljdbc4.jar is already placed in this location -sqljdbc4.jar . would there be something else causing this issue . Kindly let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> Regarding Error 1

This is not error just **warning**. `org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager` works fine for SQL Server.

> Regarding Error 2

Make sure you added `sqljdbc4.jar` in `sqoop/lib`

Comment: Note that your middle part suggests that one has to specify the driver, and that one has to specify username and password, and that one would want to set paralellism to 1. I don't think these are good (implied) suggestions. -- Placing the jar as mentioned in the bottom part is perhaps already enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Error 1** - is not an error.

**Error 2** - for accessing the MS SQL Server database Sqoop requires an additional JDBC driver which can be downloaded from Microsoft. The following steps will install MSSQL Server JDBC driver to Sqoop:

```
wget 'http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/2/A/02AAE597-3865-456C-AE7F-613F99F850A8/sqljdbc_4.0.2206.100_enu.tar.gz'

tar -xvzf sqljdbc_4

cp sqljdbc_4.0/enu/sqljdbc4.jar /usr/hdp/current/sqoop-server/lib/
```

Besides you are using integrated security, as far as I know it is not supported by Sqoop for Sql Server, so you will get **Error 3**. You have to use SQL Server security, creating a separate user and passing username-password explicitly or create a separate credentials file.

Comment: The sqljdbc4.jar is already placed in this location -sqljdbc4.jar . would there be something else causing this issue . Kindly let me know

Comment: @AnushaR This error usually occurs, when sqoop cannot find or access sqljdbc4.jar file. Either it is missing or your java version is incompatible with the driver jar file. I can advice you to double check your configurations and references